# Colormap on world map for different time steps

Tags: matlab

I have a map of the world met separation between land and sea. 
There is spreading some kind of disease with a starting point in China

i want to visualize the spread of the disease for ech week over the world, 
so the first week the disease travels for example 50 km to north and south and so further on.

so, the disease spreads well on matlab, but i want a different color for the new reached areas each day?

somebody any idea how to make this clear in the colormap? 
i have now this

```
colormap hsv
axis([-3 3 -3 3 -10 5])
% number of colors
n = 30;
% color map with red and blue on the edges
C1 = [0.7 0.8 0.3; 0.2 0.3 0.1];
% convert to HSV for interpolation
C1_HSV = rgb2hsv(C1);
% interpolate hue value
C1_HSV_interp = interp1([0 n], C1_HSV(:, 1), 1:n); 
% compose full HSV colormap
C1_HSV = [C1_HSV_interp(:), repmat(C1_HSV(2:3), n, 1)];
% convert back to RGB
C1 = hsv2rgb(C1_HSV); 
% set colormap
colormap(C1)
```

and i want to

```
if i<1                  
L(find(disease>0))=2;
elseif  i<2 
L(find(disease>0))=3;
elseif i<3
L(find(disease>0))=4;
elseif i<4
L(find(disease>0))=5; 
elseif i<5
L(find(disaese>0))=6; 
else
L(find(disease>0))=7;
```

so i want a different color for each of the values of i (spread after day X) but i don't know how to do it.

ideas?

Comment: What is `L`? It is not completely clear to me what do you want.

Comment: L refers to the raster with the number of infected people, but I think it doesn't matter for the color map creation, so the problem is really that i don't get different colors for the different times the disease spread on the map of the world.

Comment: " A picture is worth more than a thousand words" Can you shows us what you have, and what you want?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqN1DJ9rX6M  i think this short movie is an example of the thing i get done in colormap: i have something like this (but than for disease) but i want that it changes color above a certain thresold such as 1.0m-2.0m yellow, 2.0-3.0m purple, ..

Comment: You want that level to be fixed? I.e.: Red, allways between 4-5.

Comment: You may find [this](http://math.boisestate.edu/~wright/montestigliano/PlottingOnTheSphere.pdf) note about plotting on a sphere useful.

Comment: i have discovered that the real problem is not the colormap, but if you look to the 2nd part of my script, i give values from 1 to 7 for to matrix L. So, areas infected on day 1 get value 2, on day 2 get value 3, but matlab gives by this execution only 2 values in the resulting matrix: 1 for unaffected and 7 for infected no matter my time statement i=1:6 in the for loop where this part of the script is in

Answer (score 1):

By your comments it looks like you want `clims([low high])`.

Of your data can go eg. between 0 and 6 but in different time steps, you may have not all the range, you can call `clims([0 6])`. This will always draw the colormap as if the data was between that range, even if your data doesn't actually cover that range.